# Elastic Search not Indexing

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

When trying to index new users in out Django app, Elastic is unable to index...returning a key error of key ['created']

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/app/management/commands/index_users.py", line 19, in handle
    bulk_indexing(User)
  File "/home/uapp/management/commands/index_users.py", line 12, in bulk_indexing
    bulk(client=es, actions=(m.indexing() for m in model.objects.all()))
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 257, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/home//venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 180, in streaming_bulk
    client.transport.serializer):
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 58, in _chunk_actions
    for action, data in actions:
  File "/home/app/management/commands/index_users.py", line 12, in <genexpr>
    bulk(client=es, actions=(m.indexing() for m in model.objects.all().iterator()))
  File "/home/app/models.py", line 137, in indexing
    obj.save(index="users")
  File "/home/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 418, in save
    return meta['created']
KeyError: 'created'
```

User ES Index:

```
import logging
import json

from elasticsearch_dsl import Index, DocType, Integer, Text, Date, Completion, GeoPoint, analyzer, Q
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from django.conf import settings

from app.es.connection import conn

logger = logging.getLogger("app.es")


users_index = Index('users')
users_index.settings(
    number_of_shards=5,
    number_of_replicas=0
)

@users_index.doc_type
class User(DocType):
    email = Text()
    first_name = Text()
    last_name = Text()
    date_joined = Date()
    expertise = Text()
    institution = Text()
    position = Text()

    # autocomplete fields
    name_suggest = Completion(analyzer=analyzer("standard"))


def user_search(query):
    s = User.search()
    s.query = Q(Q(
        'multi_match',
        query=query,
        fields=["_all"],
        type="phrase_prefix"
    ))
    logger.info("ES query: {}".format(json.dumps(s.to_dict())))
    results = s.execute()
    logger.info("Got {} hits.".format(results.hits.total))
    payloads = []
    return [
        {
             "name": hit.name_suggest,
             "email": hit.email,
             "position": hit.position,
             "institution": hit.institution,
             "expertise": ", ".join(hit.expertise or []),
             "id": hit.meta.id,
         } for hit in results.hits]
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom Django Auth User. We can extend this to include any metadata we want on users."""

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Profile information
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    notification_preference = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=NOTIPREF, null=True)
    terms_of_service = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    expertise = models.ManyToManyField("Expertise")
    notification_preference = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=NOTIPREF, null=True)
    backup_email_address = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name) if self.first_name or self.last_name else self.email
        return full_name.strip()

    @property
    def print_queue_size(self):
        return PrintQueue.objects.filter(user=self).count()

    @property
    def notifications(self):
        return self.notifications.all()

    @property
    def notifications(self):
        return self.notifications.all()

    @property
    def num_unread_notifications(self):
        return len(self.notifications.unread())

    @property
    def expertise_str(self):
        return [str(t) for t in self.expertise.all()]

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Required by django admin"""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Sends an email to this User."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    def update(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
        self.save()

    def indexing(self):
        obj = UserDoc(
            meta={"id": self.id},
            email=self.email,
            first_name=self.first_name,x
            last_name=self.last_name,
            date_joined=self.date_joined,
            expertise=self.expertise_str,
            institution=self.institution,
            position=self.position,
            name_suggest=self.full_name,
        )
        obj.save(index="users")
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

Indexing Command:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk

from app.models import User, Resource


def bulk_indexing(model):
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(m.indexing() for m in model.objects.all().iterator()))


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Index all users'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        bulk_indexing(User)
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS("Indexed all users."))
```

The problem seems to be with the iterator. Even more odd, the auto suggest seems to work on my staging site, but no on production. Both sites are using the EXACT same code. I'm at a total loss for words.

production mapping:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "user" : {
        "properties" : {
          "date_joined" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "email" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "expertise" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "institution" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "name_suggest" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer" : "standard",
            "preserve_separators" : true,
            "preserve_position_increments" : true,
            "max_input_length" : 50
          },
          "position" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

staging mapping:

```
  "users" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : true
        },
        "properties" : {
          "date_joined" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "email" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "expertise" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "institution" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "name_suggest" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer" : "standard",
            "preserve_separators" : true,
            "preserve_position_increments" : true,
            "max_input_length" : 50
          },
          "position" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "user" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : true
        },
        "properties" : {
          "date_joined" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "email" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "expertise" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "institution" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "name_suggest" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer" : "standard",
            "preserve_separators" : true,
            "preserve_position_increments" : true,
            "max_input_length" : 50
          },
          "position" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/sixnexus/app/management/commands/index_users.py", line 17, in handle
    bulk_indexing(User)
  File "/home/ubuntu/sixnexus/app/management/commands/index_users.py", line 10, in bulk_indexing
    bulk(client=es, actions=(m.indexing() for m in model.objects.all().iterator()))
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 257, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 180, in streaming_bulk
    client.transport.serializer):
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/__init__.py", line 58, in _chunk_actions
    for action, data in actions:
  File "/home/ubuntu/sixnexus/app/management/commands/index_users.py", line 10, in <genexpr>
    bulk(client=es, actions=(m.indexing() for m in model.objects.all().iterator()))
  File "/home/ubuntu/sixnexus/app/models.py", line 137, in indexing
    obj.save(index="users")
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 419, in save
    **doc_meta
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 300, in index
    _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params, body=body)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 314, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 163, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'Rejecting mapping update to [users] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [doc, user]')
```

Comment: Please show us all the information (code) that we can run to re-create this problem or at lease to identify which line of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: @YilunZhang added some more code for clarity

Comment: @colonelrascals if you post the Elasticsearch mappings of the user document in your staging and production environments, I believe we might see the reason. Could be an extra `created` field created in the staging env, but perhaps not on production. Could be some misconfiguration/undocumented feature in the elasticsearch_dsl library. I am just guessing. The mappings might shed some light here.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena can do!

Comment: @ArchitSaxena mapping has been updated

Comment: Well doesn't look like a problem in the mappings. It seems like the elasticsearch_dsl library is wrongly looking for a `created` field in the elastic document. Might be a bug. What is the version of elasticsearch_dsl you are using?

Comment: You might want to confirm your elastic versions on staging and production. Maybe they aren't the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166711/discussion-between-archit-saxena-and-colonelrascals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It is a bug reported here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/793
Seems like your version of the library breaks in ES6 and above.

See, they have updated the line to:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/75ee4e36027cd64c128094b3ff279ec332e8a784/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py#L426
from what it was originally. It was breaking in its form: `return meta['created']`.
Upgrading the library should fix it.

Edit:
The new error is because of the fact that multiple type mappings are disallowed in ES6 and above. Note that indices migrated from 5.x with multiple mappings work in ES6. You might want to separate the types into their indices, or whatever suits your needs. This document should help there: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/removal-of-types.html

Comment: is it the same error? If so, could you confirm the contents of the elasticsearch_dsl/document.py file in your repository? It should have the updated line `return meta['result'] == 'created'`

Comment: If the answer solves the problem, would you accept it? @colonelrascals
Or let me know if there are still some issues

Comment: Thanks :) Always glad to help.